# nginx.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/nginx: No such file or directory

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services

Hello anyone can help?

I was running aws ligthsail using Nginx Instance. Everything is fine. when i configure vhosts.conf
and other conf.
when i `sudo nginx -t`
error is this:

> nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /opt/bitnami/apps/capital/conf/nginx-vhosts.conf:1
> nginx: configuration file /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed

and then i tried to check using this code `sudo service nginx status
i get this error:

> Jan 31 14:15:01 ip-172-26-12-145 systemd[5817]: nginx.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
> Jan 31 14:15:01 ip-172-26-12-145 systemd[5817]: nginx.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/nginx: No such file or directory
> Jan 31 14:15:01 ip-172-26-12-145 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
> Jan 31 14:15:01 ip-172-26-12-145 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> Jan 31 14:15:01 ip-172-26-12-145 systemd[1]: Failed to start The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server.

anyone can help please i am new using nginx server.

`

Comment: anyway i tried to look-up the file path mention on the error log which is /usr/sbin/nginx
there's is no nginx folder under on /usr/sbin/

Comment: also tried to check the status:  sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status

I got this: 

mariadb already running
nginx not running
php-fpm already running

Comment: Do you need to configure Nginx on Lightsail? Doesn't it kind of do everything for you?

Comment: thank you for the reply.. what do you mean configure nginx? is already configured i guess

Comment: Do you still have to configure "vhosts.conf and other conf" if you're using Lightsail? I thought you pretty much just uploaded some code and it did the rest.

Comment: Yes i did.. this is my code under nginx-vhosts.conf

`

server {
    listen   81;
    root   "/opt/bitnami/apps/capital/htdocs";
    server_name  capital.carketa.com;
    include "/opt/bitnami/apps/capital/conf/nginx-app.conf";
}
`

Comment: Looks like there's lots of good info here: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-quick-start-guide-nginx

Comment: The error is saying your config is wrong, it doesn't like the 'server' line.

Comment: Your nginx config is incorrect, particularly around a "server" block. If you want help with the Nginx configuration you need to share all the files that make up that configuration. Please edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

Install nginx with one of these commands:

```
sudo apt install nginx-core    
sudo apt install nginx-extras  
sudo apt install nginx-full    
sudo apt install nginx-light
```

Then you can get it working.